# Javascript Module Pattern Isolation

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I'm trying to create some isolation in javascript using the module pattern.

but when i run this code:

```
var mymap = {};

mymap['230'] = (function () {
    privatePageLoad = function(nid, page){
        console.log('PAGE LOAD from 230: '+nid);
    }

    function handleDocummentAdded() {
        console.log("New Document in 230!");
        privatePageLoad(230, 0);
    };

    return {
        newDocument: handleDocummentAdded
    }
})();

mymap['318'] = (function () {
    privatePageLoad = function(nid, page){
        console.log('PAGE LOAD from 318: '+nid);
    }

    function handleDocummentAdded() {
        console.log("New Document in 318!");
        privatePageLoad(318, 0);
    };

    return {
        newDocument: handleDocummentAdded
    }
})();

mymap['230'].newDocument();
mymap['318'].newDocument();
```

I get the following result:

```
New Document in 230! (index):29
PAGE LOAD from 318: 230 (index):40
New Document in 318! (index):44
PAGE LOAD from 318: 318
```

but i was expecting:

```
New Document in 230! (index):29
PAGE LOAD from 230: 230 (index):40
New Document in 318! (index):44
PAGE LOAD from 318: 318
```

The private method that is called is always the last added to the map...
What did i do wrong?

Here is a jsfiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/jpedro/4xdTA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare "privatePageLoad" with `var`.  Thus, it's a global variable.

You could also use a function declaration statement:

```
mymap['230'] = (function () {
    function privatePageLoad(nid, page){
        console.log('PAGE LOAD from 230: '+nid);
    }

    function handleDocummentAdded() {
        console.log("New Document in 230!");
        privatePageLoad(230, 0);
    };

    return {
        newDocument: handleDocummentAdded
    }
})();
```

Also, get into the habit of putting

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of your code. That would have resulted in an error in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`privatePageLoad` is not private at all. Add `var` , otherwise `privatePageLoad` will be global (i.e. property of the global object (window, module, whatever))

Change your code to something like:

```
var mymap = {};

mymap['230'] = (function () {
    var privatePageLoad = function(nid, page){
        console.log('PAGE LOAD from 230: '+nid);
    }

    function handleDocummentAdded() {
        console.log("New Document in 230!");
        privatePageLoad(230, 0);
    };

    return {
        newDocument: handleDocummentAdded
    }
})();

mymap['318'] = (function () {
    var privatePageLoad = function(nid, page){
        console.log('PAGE LOAD from 318: '+nid);
    }

    function handleDocummentAdded() {
        console.log("New Document in 318!");
        privatePageLoad(318, 0);
    };

    return {
        newDocument: handleDocummentAdded
    }
})();
```